# How to convert DBF file to JSON and vise versa?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I want to convert DBF File to JSON and store it in my MongoDB Database, Want my JSON Object to be converted as DBF File. I tried using **[Node-DBF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dbf)**.

Is there any other **NPM** that i could use to parse DBF and convert into **JSON** in **Node.js**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [dbf-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbf-parser) for reading dbf files, [dbf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbf) for generating dbf from JSON.